# Samba fails to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 Python error

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, python, samba

I tried to do a apt upgrade and Samba failed to upgrade:

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-urllib3_1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-urllib3_1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 27, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../python-requests_2.9.1-3ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 25, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-requests_2.9.1-3ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 27, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I've tried to force install, clean everything. From what it looks like it is failing to upgrade a dependency for samba because a python script runs and this errors. But I cannot find a solution, any help?

Cheers

Comment: Seems optparse is corrupted. try reinstalling python2 using ``sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython2.7-minimal``

Comment: Try to remove problematic deb-archive from cache with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/python-urllib3_1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb` and `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/python-requests_2.9.1-3ubuntu0.1_all.deb`. Then resume installation with `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` .

Comment: Thanks guys, so @Anunay this resulted in
`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python-samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.15) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.17 is to be installed`

@N0rbert, this resulted in the same message as above :(

I think that python is the problem and that needs reinstalling but because samba is bust it's preventing me from reinstalling. I guess I need to fix python manually?

Comment: @marcusorjames Did you try --force installing it, as ``apt-get -f install libpython2.7-minimal``